# Workflow on tasks list will not run on items created by a workflow

Tags: workflow, tasks

I have a globally reusable workflow assigned to the 'tasks' content type that sends an email to remind a user one day before the due date of a task.

When an item is manually created inside the tasks list, the email workflow will run fine and send an email reminder perfectly.

I also have a publishing workflow inside another library. The publishing workflow creates tasks for users to complete. however any task created by the workflow will not run the reusable email workflow.

the email workflow is set to kick off whenever an item is created or changed, so there should be no reason why the workflow does not run.

Is this MS intended to stop the chance of recursion, or is it unexpected?

Answer (score 1):

If the secondary workflow(workflow on tasks list) is triggered by a process that is running under the system account, e.g. An item update after some kind of async process, then the workflow will not trigger. This is a security feature added by microsoft in sharepoint.

Also check : [Secondary workflow on task list not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16142/secondary-workflow-on-task-list-not-working)