# Task workflow not firing on task created by information management policy

Tags: 2013, 2010, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks

I have a requirement to send out a custom notification email whenever a new task is assigned to a user. To achieve this I have turned off the standard notification on the Tasks list and attached a simple SP Designer workflow to send out notification emails instead. This works properly when I add a task to the list via the front end **but not when one is added by an information management policy**

I'm guessing this is because of the "workflows won't run on tasks created by the system account" issue as seen on SO here:
[Workflow on tasks list will not run on items created by a workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/101294/workflow-on-tasks-list-will-not-run-on-items-created-by-a-workflow)
here:
[Secondary workflow on task list not working](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/16142/secondary-workflow-on-task-list-not-working)
and here:
https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3653/task-created-by-sharepoint-designer-workflow-not-firing-a-workflow

I've tried possible fix of deploying the "task creation" workflow using a different account and also my own recipe of doing the actual task creation using an impersonation step but sadly both options still create tasks using the system account and the notification workflow does not run.

Does anyone know of a way that I can either
1. get the information management policy to create tasks as something other than the system account
or
2. change the default task notification text by some other means then replacing it with a workflow

More background:
This is a SharePoint 2010 designer workflow running on a 2013 installation and the information management policy I refer to is a retention policy to create a reminder task when a review date field on a document is reached.
Edit - even more background - the task type I'm using is "Collect Data from a User" which pauses workflow execution until it is completed, hence I can't just create the task and then send an email as the email wouldn't be sent until the task was already complete!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is it not possible to run a workflow as Information Management Policy action, get that workflow to create the task and change notification text as required ?

When you create a new task, you get a "created" variable returned, ID/GUID of the task created. This allows you to make further modifications on newly created tasks.

Comment: Hi Charles. That would be possible, however I would prefer to run the workflow in the context of the Task list so can access the related item information. Thanks Tim